# Access "Anyone with link" properties (and link) using REST API

Tags: rest-api, permissions, sharing, http

I have an attachment with "Anyone with link" sharing configuration. How can I retrieve (or construct) the actual sharing URL using the rest API?

E.g., I have an attachment with id: 069240000009bdU and ViewAll permissions through Rest API. From UI (web) I can see that its URL is: https://eu5.salesforce.com/sfc/p/24000000Iv3d/a/240000004F9m/Hvn9E4Bsh19gqu0BLW7AKRCqa48rilU8pSTVEq5HuXU

How can I get this URL through Rest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could consider switching over to using Content rather than Attachment then you can use the [ContentDistribution](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm).DistributionPublicUrl. This is circa Winter 15 and the idea [Allow Content Deliveries to be programmatically generated via Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HMq4AAG).